# Regex: Return highest number of string containing year range

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, performance

I have the following three ranges containing years stored as strings:

```
year1 = '2006-07'
year2 = '2006-2007'
year3 = '2020/21'
```

I want to create a function that returns the higher year. For the variables above, the results would be as follows:

```
year1 -> 2007
year2 -> 2007
year3 -> 2021
```

What's the most efficient method of solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the built-in date parsing in python. The only trick is deciding whether to use the format `"%Y"` or `"%y"` which depends on whether you are passing in a two-digit year or a four-digit year. You can pull the numbers out of the string with `re.findall()` which is a little simpler than split here and has the advantage of working with multiple separators:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

def maxYear(y):
    toFormat = lambda s: "%y" if len(s) == 2 else "%Y"
    years = re.findall(r'\d+', y)
    return max(datetime.strptime(s, toFormat(s)) for s in years).year


maxYear('2006-07')
# 2007
maxYear('2006-2007')
# 2007
maxYear('2020/21')
# 2021

# Edge cases:
maxYear("1999/00")
# 2000

maxYear("1967/68")
# 2068 <- datetime century cuttoff is 1968

maxYear("1967/69")
# 1969

# it's flexible
maxYear('2021:2000:2022:1968:10')
# 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate ranges and use `max`:

```
import re
def max_year(d):
   vals = re.split('[\/\-]', d)
   x, y = [i for i in vals if len(i) == 4], [i for i in vals if len(i) != 4]
   return max(map(int, x+[x[0][:2]+i for i in y]))

year1 = '2006-07'
year2 = '2006-2007'
year3 = '2020/21'
print(max_year(year1))
print(max_year(year2))
print(max_year(year3))
```

Output:

```
2007
2007
2021
```

Comment: Years like `'1999-01'` are problematic and assumptions about dates like this are a common cause of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your expected patterns

```
(\d{4})
```

or

```
(20\d{2})
```

should work. Take matched groups and sort them.

This is a good site to test your expressions: https://regex101.com/#python